# When $Hom_{R'}(R, S)$ is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R\subseteq  S$ be a ring extension of commutative rings with identity. It is well-known that we can consider $Hom_{R'}(R, S)$ as an $R'$-module in a natural way, where $Hom_{R'}(R, S)$ is the set of all $R'$-module homomorphsms form the $R'$-module $R$ to the $R'$-module $S$  when $R'$ is another commutative ring and we can conside $R$ and $S$ as $R'$-modules. Is there any condition on $R$ or $S$ such that $Hom_{R'}(R, S)$ be also a commutative ring?

Comment: Do you run in to any difficulties if you just specify multiplication pointwise?

Comment: This Hom is just $S$ again.

Comment: So sorry.  The question is corrected.